# Using knockoutjs with KoGrid not working Chrome or FF but works in IE8

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am new to KnockOutJs and I am implementing it as well as KoGrid.  I have a grid set up that populates data from the data in IE8 but does not work in Chrome or FF.

Javascript -

```
function FillViewModel(data) {
    var vm = {
        MyResults: ko.observableArray(data)
    };

    return vm;
}

$(function () {
    $.post("/Controller/Search", function (returnedData) {

        ko.applyBindings(FillViewModel(JSON.parse(returnedData)));
    })
});
```

The method in the controller.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string Search()
    {
        List<myData> resultList;
        resultList= _context.SelectAll();

        JavaScriptSerializer s = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string json = s.Serialize(resultList);

        return json;
    }
```

Then I am populating it in my view as such.

```
    <div id="myTable" data-bind="koGrid: { data: MyResults}">
    </div>
```

As I said, it populates fine all 200 something rows in IE, but when I try to run it in FF or Chrome, it appears to all be called but the grid never shows.

Comment: Can you show the part of the page where you include koGrid and knockout?

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  But I had a display: none that was taking over.  What it came down to was I had some html 5 content that was being ignored in IE8 (hence the display: none on the object was being ignored" but Chrome and FF would recognize the html5 element and so the grid wouldn't show because of the display on it. Silly error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a display: none that was taking over. What it came down to was I had some html 5 content that was being ignored in IE8 (hence the display: none on the object was being ignored" but Chrome and FF would recognize the html5 element and so the grid wouldn't show because of the display on it. Silly error.